# Regex performance between or (|) and any ([]+)

Tags: regex, visual-c++

I am using visual c++ tr1

My regex is trying to match "bar", strings can be

```
foo bar class
foo;bar
foo; bar
bar foo
bar
```

the regex I am using was

```
(^|[; ]+)bar\\s+
```

This is very slow for some reason, if I change regex to

```
(^|;|\\s)bar\\s+
```

It gives me a huge speedup. By the way, I am using regex_search function.

Could anybody explain why is this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These expressions are not equivilent.  The first takes any number of `;` semicolons and spaces, while the second takes only one.  It might help to see some of the text you are matching.

The reason for the performance difference is probably 'backtracking'.  In the first expression, `(^|[; ]+)bar\\s+`, there is the potential for backtracking at the begining of the expression.  In `(^|;|\\s)bar\\s+`, there can be no backtracking.  Backtracking means reattempting a different path through the data based on a different path through the regex.  (However, if it is really `bar` that you are searching for, there shouldn't be much differnece.)

Comment: Thanks for explanation, I have added some strings I try to match, any suggestions how to optimize this is also welcome.

Comment: Do you /want/ just the first, or all the semicolons and spaces before bar and all the spaces after bar?

Comment: I actually only cares if string matches, I do not need matched patterns to be processed later. i.e. I only need a boolean out of the match.

Comment: If you want to have a better performance use this:  `"(?:^|[\\s])bar\\s"`.  The `?:` makes it a non-capturing group, which improves performance by reducing the amount of work the engine does.  I removed the `+` greedy multipilier at the end because you only care if it matches, not what the match is.

Comment: Good point, thanks! I modified my query to use word boundary in front of bar and got another huge improvement. I am still not clear on why I received big speedup by not using grouping []+